# "while at the same time" + -ing form?

Tags: verbs, tenses, clauses, ing

In following sentence, I'm not sure if I have to use the -ing form or the infinitive.

> I wanted to get rid of X, while at the same time not assuming/ assume
>   that...

The -ing form sounds better, but the infinitive doesn't sound too wrong either.
Which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal preference as far as I can tell. I don't like either sentence structure because they're both verbose:

> I wanted to get rid of my old car, while at the same time **not assuming** that my parents would buy me a new one for my birthday.
>
> I wanted to get rid of my old car, while at the same time **not assume** that my parents would buy me a new one for my birthday.

I'd suggest:

> I wanted to get rid of my old car **without assuming** that my parents would buy me a new one for my birthday.
> or
> I wanted to get rid of my old car **but not assume** that my parents would buy me a new one for my birthday.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *at the same time* is functioning as an adverbial, so the clause without it is

> while ... assuming that

I would not say *while assume that*, so I would not say *while at the same time assume that*.